# How to get the $static_token variable from within the managewishlist.tpl file in Prestashop 1.6.1.x

Tags: prestashop-1.6, smarty3, prestashop-modules

I'm using the following two lines to create a 'Buy' button inside the managewishlist.tpl file (within my theme modules folder):

```
{capture}add={$product.quantity|intval}&amp;id_product={$product.id_product|intval}{if isset($product.id_product_attribute) && $product.id_product_attribute}&amp;ipa={$product.id_product_attribute|intval}{/if}{if isset($static_token)}&amp;token={$static_token}{/if}{/capture}
<a class="btn btn-default ajax_add_to_cart_button add-to-cart-wishlist-button" href="{$link->getPageLink('cart', true, NULL, $smarty.capture.default, false)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" data-id-attribute="{$product.id_product_attribute}" data-id-product="{$product.id_product|intval}" data-minimal_quantity="{$product.quantity|intval}" title="{l s='Add to cart' mod='blockwishlist'}"><span>{l s='Buy' mod='blockwishlist'}</span></a>
```

...and the $static_token variable is apparently not available to the template.

Answer (score 0):

I was originally asking this as a serious question to move on with my project, but I figured it out so I thought I would share the solution as well.

In the /modules/blockwishlist/managewishlist.php file - you need to add the following line:

```
    $context->smarty->assign(array('static_token' => Tools::getToken(false))); /* make $static_token available in tpl */
```

just before this line:

```
    $action = Tools::getValue('action');
```